# supporting multiple dialog boxes on web page with jquery through traversing the DOM

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-traversing

I have tried every combination that I can think of and for some reason can't get this code to run properly.The dialog method is correct. When i call ".dialog" directly after click without trying to traverse, everything runs fine. If I have multiple dialog boxes they will all open one after the other.

Is this possible with traversing? am I missing something?

I hope this isn't too vague, if there are any questions please let me know.

Thank you in advance for any help!

My code is below:

html:

```
       <div class = "opener">Click for Item Numbers</div>
        <div class = "dialog" title = "Dialog">
           Dialog box
          </div>



      <div class = "opener">Click for Item Numbers</div>
        <div class = "dialog" title = "Dialog">
           Dialog box
         </div>
```

jquery:

```
 //jquery ui dialog box

   $('.dialog').dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     modal: true,
     show: {
       effect: "blind",
       duration: 1000
      },
     hide: {
      effect: "explode",
      duration: 1000
    }

 })

  //jquery open function for dialog

$(function() {

 $('.opener').on('click', function () {
  $(this).next('div.dialog').dialog('open');


    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM gets all rearranged when you start with `.dialog()`. My recommendation is to save the element before creating it as a dialog, and then open it via reference.

```
$(function () {

   $('.opener').each(function () {
       $(this).data('dialog', $(this).next('div.dialog'));
   });

   //jquery ui dialog box

   $('.dialog').dialog({
       autoOpen: false,
       modal: true,
       show: {
           effect: "blind",
           duration: 1000
       },
       hide: {
           effect: "explode",
           duration: 1000
       }

   });

   //jquery open function for dialog

   $('.opener').on('click', function () {
       $(this).data('dialog').dialog('open');


   });
});
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/q8m844so/

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you very much. I don't quite understand the methodology behind this, but it definitley works! I'll be looking over .data() method and .each() to see what I can learn.